# Não consigo fazer SELECT

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-select

Model:

```
public function exibir_noticia()
{  

  $consulta = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM Noticia_Site_Cairu');
  return $consulta->result();
}
```

Controller

```
public function index()

{
    $this->load->model('noticia_model');
    $consulta = $this->noticia_model->exibir_noticia();         
    //print_r($casdatrado);
    $this->load->view('v_home', $consulta);
}
```

Quando vou exibir na view:

```
                foreach ($consulta as $exibir):{            
                echo '                  
                <tr class="success">
                    <td>'.$exibir->titulo.'</td>
                    <td>'.$exibir->texto.'</td>
                    <td>'.$exibir->imagem.'</td>
                    <td>'.$exibir->link.'</td>
                    <td>'.$exibir->nome_link.'</td>
                    <td>'.$exibir->video.'</td>
                    <td>'.$exibir->data.'</td>
                </tr>';
                }endforeach;
```

Aparece esse erro:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: consulta
>
> Filename: views/v_home.php
>
> Line Number: 88
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /var/www/html/admnoticias/application/views/v_home.php Line: 88
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /var/www/html/admnoticias/application/controllers/Home.php Line:
>   17 Function: view
>
> File: /var/www/html/admnoticias/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$consulta` não existe na view porque não foi definida, veja o código do controller:

```
$this->load->view('v_home', $consulta);
```

Para definir o nome da variável que será manipulada na view crie um array associativo:

```
$this->load->view('v_home', array('consulta' => $consulta));
```

Comment: Obrigado funcionou!
Sempre terei que colocar um array???
pensei que bastasse enviar a variavel fosse o suficiente.
Muito obrigado!

Comment: @web_charles sim sempre, isso é comum. Veja que no seu exemplo vc passou apenas uma variável, e se fossem mais como faria? um array não seria mais prático? :)

Comment: é verdade! Obrigado pela dica ;)

Comment: @web_charles vc pode marcar uma das respostas como 'aceita' (sinal verde) isso significa que uma delas resolveu o seu problema. Pode ver mais detalhes em: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91).